# Quick Sort Implementation in Python [particular input crashes]

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

I'm writing a quick_sort algorithm code. This is the code that should work in my knowledge and which works for most arrays but it doesn't work on [5, 3, 9, 8, 6] and spits out **IndexError: list index out of range**

```
def quick_sort_array(A):
    return quick_sort(A, 0, len(A)-1)

def quick_sort(A, l, r):
    if l < r:
        pivot = A[l]
        left = l + 1
        right = r
        while left <= right:
            while A[left] <= pivot:
                left += 1
            while A[right] >= pivot and left <= right:
                right -= 1
            if left <= right:
                tmp = A[left]
                A[left] = A[right]
                A[right] = tmp
        A[l] = A[right]
        A[right] = pivot

        quick_sort(A, l, right-1)
        quick_sort(A, right+1, r)
```

Can you please help me in understanding this? Thanks

Error Message:
[image: Error Message for particular input]

Comment: In the call that fails, what are the values of the parameters? That should allow you to quickly find the error. Also, try to find a video tutorial showing you how to step through code with a debugger.

Comment: Thanks @Ulrich, that helps as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation of the partition step of Quicksort fails when the pivot is the largest element between the start of part of the list you're partitioning and the end of the list. The `while` loop that increases `left` can keep going until it runs off the end of the list.

To fix the issue, you need to stop the first inner loop from running past `right`, just like you already prevent `right` from running too far past `left`. I've not verified exactly what boundary condition you want, but just copying the one from the second inner loop will probably work:

```
        while A[left] <= pivot and left <= right:
            left += 1
        while A[right] >= pivot and left <= right:
            right -= 1
```